# Python Regex, Get Actual Line Back

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to regex over an entire file, however I keep ending up with a list like this:

```
NONE
NONE
NONE
NONE
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f89b0152db0>
NONE
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f89b0152db0>
```

How do I get the actual line back?

Here is my code:

```
 dictionaryFile = "file.txt"
 patternMatch = re.compile('^(\w{6,8})(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(.+)(\s+)(\d{1,3}\s*-\s*\d{1,3})')

 with open(dictionaryFile) as file:
     for line in file:
          result = patternMatch.search(line)
          print result
```

Here is an example of the file I am regex'ing over:

```
HETELAVL        2       IS THERE A TELEPHONE ELSEWHERE ON           35 - 36
                WHICH PEOPLE IN THIS HOUSEHOLD CAN 
                BE CONTACTED?

                EDITED UNIVERSE:    HETELHHD = 2

                VALID ENTRIES

                1   YES
                2   NO

 HEPHONEO       2       IS A TELEPHONE INTERVIEW ACCEPTABLE?            37 - 38

                EDITED UNIVERSE:    HETELHHD = 1 OR HETELAVL = 1

                VALID ENTRIES
                1   YES
                2   NO
```

I would like to get this back:

```
HETELAVL        2       IS THERE A TELEPHONE ELSEWHERE ON           35 - 36
HEPHONEO        2       IS A TELEPHONE INTERVIEW ACCEPTABLE?            37 - 38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns `None` *if no position in the string matches the pattern*.

Check if the `result` is not `None` and print `line`:

```
result = patternMatch.search(line)
if result is not None:
    print line
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! That is far to simple for me not to have figured out.

Answer (score 0):

search returns a match object so don't just print it as it will print the object use result.group(0) to get the actual line.